# Jmeter place character into extracted json value

Tags: jmeter

i'm trying to create a performance test using Jmeter (i'm a beginners with this program).
I have a request that use JSON xtractor to take a varible to use into a new request, this the code:

```
$.versionInfo.versionGuid
```

and the value of variable is like this:

```
{2435sf-hdhdjd-gdhsytrw-dggdteo}
```

Now i need to replace the "{" and "}" with nothing; i need to remove these characters.
How can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is really what you're looking for one of the options is using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) which allows you executing arbitrary [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) so you can remove these curly brackets like:

```
${__groovy(vars.put('myVar'\, vars.get('myVar').replace('{'\,'').replace('}'\,'')),)}
```

Replace `myVar` with your actual [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) name you define in the [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor).

Demo:

[image]

---

Also it might be the case you need to amend your JSON Extractor configuration or switch to J[SON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) to extract only the guid you're looking for, but we need to see your JSON in order to suggest how this could be done.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your reply. I have to set this new variable into url of a second request. So i can set this groovy function into a pre-process?